# get id of all checked checkboxes in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to dynamically append checkboxes inside a div.

I want a javascript function to do the following :

- When I check a checkbox: add its id to an array.
- When I uncheck a checkbox: remove the id from that array.

This is what I've done so far:

```
var chkArray = [];
$(".Checked:checked").each(function () {
    chkArray.push($(this).attr("id"));
});
var selected;
selected = chkArray.join(',') + ",";
if (selected.length > 1) {
    return chkArray;
}
```

Comment: Please Post your HTML

Comment: Do you have the class `Checked` on the div or on the checkboxes? In your code you are creating a string from the array to check if there is anything in the array. Why not check the length of the array instead?

Comment: It's common Stack Overflow courtesy to at least reply to people trying to help you. I also notice that you have asked a few questions but haven't accepted any answers even though they look valid. Please remember to accept answers that helped you out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Take your `$checkbox` jQuery object and use [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) to select only those that are checked
- Use [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) to map the remaining elements to their `id` property
- Use [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) to get an array representation of the resulting jQuery object

```js
function checkArray($checkbox) {
    return $checkbox
        .filter(':checked')
        .map((_, el) => el.id)
        .get();
}

$checkbox = $('.Checked');
$checkbox.change(() => console.log(checkArray($checkbox)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="Checked" id="ch1" type="checkbox">
<input class="Checked" id="ch2" type="checkbox">
<input class="Checked" id="ch3" type="checkbox">
<input class="Checked" id="ch4" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: I like this elegant solution. By the way, a note to the OP — the checking/unchecking thing is already handled by the default, so all you need is just that when a checkbox is clicked on (or changed), you go through the array of checkboxes and return the IDs of those that are checked, as simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I'd do:

```
var checkedArray = [];

$(":checkbox").change(function(){
  if((this).checked){
    checkedArray.push(this.id);
  }
  else{
    checkedArray.splice(checkedArray.indexOf(this.id), 1);
  }

  //you can call your function here if you need to act on this.

});
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/redders6600/pen/CwnBa)

Answer (score 2):

If you want all checkboxes on your page to be scanned, use `querySelectorAll` with a css selector that tells the command to look for all checkboxes and select only the ones that are checked:

```
var checked_boxes = document.querySelectorAll('[type^="checkbox"]:checked');
```

If you want only a subset of checkboxes to be scanned, first give the same name attribute to all of them (e.g., `name="group-1"`) and use instead:

```
var checked_boxes = document.querySelectorAll('[name^="group-1"]:checked');
```

The variable `checked_boxes` is now a list of nodes. You may now get attributes from each node, such as the id, to build a list as you want.

Answer (score 1):

I tested George's jsfiddle and couldn't get it to work but edited his code and made it work you can try this is works

```
 $('#PostAlert').click(function GetID() {

            $checkbox = $('.CheckBxMSG');
            var chkArray = [];
            chkArray = $.map($checkbox, function (el) {
                if (el.checked) { return el.id };
            });
            alert(chkArray);
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead  take your form id and while submitting check what are all check boxes checked like   this

```
$("#formid input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
  var chkArray = [];
  chkArray.push($(this).id());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you described

```
var checkboxes = $("input[type=checkbox]");
var r = [];

checkboxes.on("change",function(e){ 
    if(!e.target.id){
        return;  
    } 
    if(e.target.checked){
        r.push(e.target.id);
    }
    else{
        var index = r.indexOf(e.target.id)
        if(~index){
            r.splice(index, 1);
        }               
    }
    console.log(r);
});
```